# How to set theme id property on Components?

Tags: themes, custom-controls, xpages

Whatever I do, only theme set in application properties applies. Theme id doesnt work as expected.

For example:

I have two custom controls and each has 5 views. I try to set view title property for all views in first custom control with theme and same with second custom control, but with different theme (and title).

Both custom controls exist on same page.

Problem Im trying to solve is, instead of typing functions for properties for each component of same type I want to do it only in one place. In that case all views in one custom control. Or all views in a panel...

Comment: This caught me out for a while. The ThemeID of a control is to control which rules in the application theme get applied to the control, like a class in CSS. It's not there to specify a completely different Theme. e.g. you can put in Button.Submit or Button.Fancy in the ThemeID to control a variation and put config in the Theme which only applies to those versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Themes: afaik we only can define a single theme per application. This theme can inherit from other themes but those need to be installed and registered at the file system level for the entire server.

Regarding your scenario:

If you really want to solve that with themes you could work with separate theme ids. But I really don't see the benefit of using themes here. As far as I understand your task I would solve it using custom properties for your custom controls. The view title would then be computed to reference that property as in

```
<xp:viewTitle xp:key="viewTitle" id="viewTitle1"
    value="#{javascript:compositeData.ccViewTitle}">
</xp:viewTitle>
```

At design time the containing Xpage or Custom Control would then feed the appropriate view title to the child control:

```
<xc:ccInner ccViewTitle="View Title for First CC in Page"></xc:ccInner>
<xc:ccInner ccViewTitle="View Title for Second CC in Page"></xc:ccInner>
```

You also could compute this value, if necessary.

Comment: That should solve it. Will report with implementation.